# JS-libp2p Tutorial Doc "Error: Cannot find module 'libp2p'"

Tags: node.js, libp2p

I wanted to start learning to use libp2p and so started up the tutorial documentation and have hit a problem right away.

The Docs: https://docs.libp2p.io/tutorials/getting-started/javascript/

Following along I got to the "Run Libp2p" header. Running the script I get the error message `Error: Cannot find module 'libp2p'`

When install the module with `sudo npm install libp2p` there was an error reading:

`ursaNative bindings compilation fail. This is not an issue. Modules that depend on it will use fallbacks.
fs.js:115
    throw err;`
    ^

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open './stdout.log'
at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1190:35)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/foss/hello-libp2p/node_modules/ursa-optional/rebuild.js:13:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
npm WARN hello-libp2p@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN hello-libp2p@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ursa-optional@0.10.1 install: `node rebuild.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ursa-optional@0.10.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-29T11_05_48_715Z-debug.log
```

`

I'm not really sure why there's a permission denied portion of the error as this was run as sudo.The problem seems to revolve around that ursa script. Although it might be optional I'm not sure. Does anyone who has worked with libp2p seen this before?

I'm using node12.16.1 and npm6.13.4 on ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Well I just found this. Earlier in the shell after trying to install libp2p it says that it doesn't support node version 10.x.x and I should upgrade. But why I check my version of node i'm running 12?

Comment: So I went and tried to reinstall node by first running `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove nodejs`, and then reinstalling it via binary instructions(https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation) because for some reason the ppa method is broken for 19.10 for both node 12&13. But when I try to `install libp2p` it tells me `sudo: npm: command not found`. So I run `sudo apt install npm` but this again results in throwing an error citing the old node version 10. This is because the default repos seem to be for Node v10.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to, instead of running `sudo npm i libp2p` after manually installing the binaries, I had to just skip the sudo and it all works fine. This cause a problem though because I can't install modules globally now because using sudo throws the no npm command found.... I'm not too sure how to add the npm path back into the commands for sudo, or why npm is not present in sudo but is regularly.... This is strange. Will likely be resolved with other distros that natively support node v12 instead of v10. Hopefully 20.04lts will fix this.